# Download video file using DownloadManager in Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am  new to Android, am working on a project which downloads files from given url,it works fine for mp3 but am not able to download video files and if it is downloaded than it does not open....plz help
my code is like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    String myUrl = "my url";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadManager.Request request=new 
        DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myUrl));
        request.setTitle("download");
        request.setDescription("your file is downloading ...");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

  request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"testing.mp4");

DownloadManager manager =(DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Comment: Try adding this line: `request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)`

Comment: @SaurabhThorat t thank u so much sir,it started working but I could'nt understand how it started working by adding this line??

Comment: I'll post that as an answer so it might be of help to others

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

`request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWO‌​RK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)`